# Numbering not every line with lineno

Tags: line-numbering

How it is possible to number not every line with [lineno](http://ctan.tug.org/pkg/lineno)?

For example only every fifth line.

There are no hints in the manual.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Page 2 of my copy of the manual mentions the `modulo` option: *"Print line numbers only if they are multiples of five"*.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[modulo]{lineno}
\linenumbers

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And the command `\modulolinenumbers[4]` changes from numbering every five lines to four.