# Automatically numbering lines on a two column document for some numbers and not all of them

Tags: numbering, paragraphs

I have two column document in which I wish insert line numbers. I have used `\usepackege{lineno}`, I used `\linenumbers` for inserting line numbers at the left of the left column, and `\rightlinenumbers` for inserting line numbers at the right of the right column.  But there are several problems:

1- I wish to have automatically left and right numbering and not manually. In the above mentioned procedure, we have to manually insert for example `\rightlinenumbers`.

2- I could not understand how we can insert some numbers and not all numbers: For example, 1, 5, 15, 20,... and not 1,2,3,4,....

How can I do these wishes?!

Also, upon below answer, we used `\usepackage[switch]{lineno}` but result is as

[image]

Unfortunately it does not work!!! Numbers does not emerge at the left of the left column!!!

Comment: Regarding your second request, the `lineno` package option `modulo` might  be useful. If you want a dfferent numbering scheme than numbering every fifth line, `\modulolinenumbers[<number>]` might be interesting.

Comment: Related: [Lineno for 2 column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20368/134144) and [Numbering not every line with lineno](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56507/134144)

Comment: Wonderful, thankx

Comment: You need to run twice to get the line number in the proper columns.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, you can invoke lineno with the option `switch`.  Be sure to run twice for the correct outcome.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\lipsum{1-24}

\end{document}
```

[image]